# How to do DataBinding with c# and XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I`m trying to deserialize an XML file, and put the info. in to a listBox in XAML with the help of DataBingingList.
I have the following code in my Test.cs file:

```
[XmlRoot("product")]
public class Test
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("categoryname")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name{get;set;}

    [XmlElement("price")]
    public Price price { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("description")]
    public description Description { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name + " " + price + " " + Description;
    }

    public BindingList<Test> all = new BindingList<Test>();
}
[XmlRoot("price")]
public class Price
{
    [XmlAttribute("unit")]
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public int p { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Unit + " " + p;
    }
}
[XmlRoot("description")]
public class description
{
    [XmlElement("color")]
    public string Color { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("size")]
    public string Size { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("weight")]
    public string Weight { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Color + " " + " " + Size + " " + Weight;
    }
```

And here is the code in my MainWindows.xaml.cs

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
         InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            Test test = new Test();
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"ajde.xml");
            test = (Test)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
            ListBox1.ItemsSource = test.all; // ListBox from MainWindow.xaml
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }`
```

}

In my MainWindows.xaml I want to be able to do something like Value="{Binding Path= Description}"...

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please go to google and type wpf mvvm tutorials [or click here](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=wpf%20mvvm%20tutorials) and you can easily learn  how to do something like `Value="{Binding Path= Description}"`.

Comment: Please post the code for your test class as well